# Solve DFE $2y'^2 = 2x^2y' - 3xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the DFE $$2y'^2 = 2x^2y' - 3xy.$$
I started with substituting $p = dy/dx$ and obtained
$2p^2 = 2x^2p - 3xy$. I isolated $y$ and got $$y = \frac{2}{3} \left[xp - \frac{p^2}{x}\right].$$ Taking the derivative yields: $$y' = p'= \frac{2}{3}\left[p'x + p - \frac{p(2xp' - p)}{x^2}\right].$$
And that's where I draw blank. I tried factorizing, but at no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: When you make that substitution with p all the y's need to be gone and everything needs to be in terms of p

Comment: @TehRod, all the $y$'s are gone (with the derivative) and I tried factorizing, but it didn't work. Do you have an alternative method for solving this?

Comment: $y' = p$, not $p'$. That's probably why the factorization didn't work.

Comment: @querty I've been looking at it and I have nothing sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

$$\tag 1 2y'^2 = 2x^2y' - 3xy.$$

Setting $p = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in $(1)$ and solving for $y$, we get

$$\tag 2  y = \dfrac{2}{3} (x p - x^{-1} p^2)$$

Differentiating $(2)$

$$\tag 3 y' = p = \dfrac{2}{3}(p + x p' + x^{-2} p^2 -2x^{-1} p p')$$

Factoring $(3)$

$$\tag 4 (x^2 - 2 p)(2 x p' - p) = 0$$

I will assume you can take it from here.

Comment: you're my saviour :) One thing though: shouldn't it be $-2x^{-1}pp'$ in step (4)?

Comment: Yes - just a typo - had it correct in my scribblings - will update.